# pandas - delete duplicates from dataframe by values of 2 columns but with preserving values of 3rd column

Tags: pandas, filter, duplicates

I have the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
# Define the data
data = { 
    'order': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G'],
    'event_out': ['GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_3', pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, 'GUID_1_5', 'GUID_1_5', 'GUID_1_5', 'GUID_1_5'],
    'event_in': ['GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_4', 'GUID_2_4', 'GUID_2_4', 'GUID_2_4', pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA]
}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

display(df)
```

```
        order   event_out   event_in
0   A   GUID_1_1    GUID_2_1
1   A   GUID_1_1    GUID_2_2
2   A   GUID_1_1    GUID_2_3
3   A   GUID_1_2    GUID_2_1
4   A   GUID_1_2    GUID_2_2
5   A   GUID_1_2    GUID_2_3
6   A   GUID_1_3    GUID_2_1
7   A   GUID_1_3    GUID_2_2
8   A   GUID_1_3    GUID_2_3
9   B   GUID_1_1    GUID_2_1
10  B   GUID_1_1    GUID_2_2
11  B   GUID_1_1    GUID_2_3
12  B   GUID_1_2    GUID_2_1
13  B   GUID_1_2    GUID_2_2
14  B   GUID_1_2    GUID_2_3
15  B   GUID_1_3    GUID_2_1
16  B   GUID_1_3    GUID_2_2
17  B   GUID_1_3    GUID_2_3
18  C   GUID_1_1    GUID_2_1
19  C   GUID_1_1    GUID_2_2
20  C   GUID_1_1    GUID_2_3
21  C   GUID_1_2    GUID_2_1
22  C   GUID_1_2    GUID_2_2
23  C   GUID_1_2    GUID_2_3
24  C   GUID_1_3    GUID_2_1
25  C   GUID_1_3    GUID_2_2
26  C   GUID_1_3    GUID_2_3
27  D   <NA>        GUID_2_4
28  D   <NA>        GUID_2_4
29  E   <NA>        GUID_2_4
30  E   <NA>        GUID_2_4
31  F   GUID_1_5    <NA>
32  F   GUID_1_5    <NA>
33  G   GUID_1_5    <NA>
34  G   GUID_1_5    <NA>
```

If any GUID in columns event_out and event_in is already used for any order, then other rows with the same GUID must be deleted.
If row with GUIDs for some order is kept in dataset, then other rows for the same order must be ignored.
GUID used in event_out cannot appear in event_in and vice versa.

So after filtering data the final dataset have to be the following:

```
data = { 
    'order': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'],
    'event_out': ['GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_3', pd.NA, 'GUID_1_5'],
    'event_in': ['GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_4', pd.NA]
}

# Create the DataFrame
df_filtered = pd.DataFrame(data)

display(df_filtered)
```

```
        order   event_out   event_in
0   A   GUID_1_1    GUID_2_1
1   B   GUID_1_2    GUID_2_2
2   C   GUID_1_3    GUID_2_3
3   D   <NA>        GUID_2_4
4   F   GUID_1_5    <NA>
```

Thank you.

Tried to use groupby for filtering but didn't achieve the desired result.
Looking for a solution avoiding processing the data in the loop, like this:

```
df_unique = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
     if (row['order']  not in df_unique['order'].values) and \
        ((pd.isna(row['event_out'])) or (row['event_out'] not in df_unique['event_out'].values)) and \
        ((pd.isna(row['event_in']))  or (row['event_in'] not in df_unique['event_in'].values)):
         df_unique = df_unique.append(row)
        
display(df_unique)
```

Comment: `df_filtered = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['event_out'], keep='first')` Will return your intended output

Comment: it will keep 3 first records for order A, but they should be for A, B, C

Comment: I doubt this can be achieved in a vectorial way. Also, how to handle circular cases? Which row should have priority? Should you have at least one of each order? The logic is probably much more complex than what you illustrated with a single example.

Comment: logic is not too complex. f do it with a cycle then I need to iterate initial dataset and check that order is not in a target dataset. If it is not, then to check that both, event_out guid and event_in guid, are not used earlier. If they are not used, then add a row to a target dataset and go to the next row of the source dataset.

Comment: Why don't you provide this code for clarity?

Comment: @mozway, I put this code in the end of the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

More optimal way I found:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate test data for columns A and B with duplicates
np.random.seed(42)
data = {
    'A': np.random.randint(1, 5, 20),
    'B': np.random.randint(10, 13, 20),
}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(df)
# Create an empty DataFrame to store extracted records
extracted_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'])

while not df.empty:
    # Extract the first record from the DataFrame
    first_record = df.iloc[0:1]

    # Append the first record to the extracted DataFrame
    extracted_df = extracted_df.append(first_record, ignore_index=True)

    # Remove records with the same value in column A or B as the first record
    df = df.loc[(df['A'] != first_record['A'].iloc[0]) & (df['B'] != first_record['B'].iloc[0])]

# Display the extracted DataFrame
print("Extracted DataFrame:")
display(extracted_df)
```

Answer (score -1):

The drop_duplicates method in pandas can be used to remove duplicates from a DataFrame based on the values of two columns while keeping the values of a third column you can try like this, see if it works

```
import pandas as pd

# Define data
data = { 
    'order': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G'],
    'event_out': ['GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_1', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_2', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_3', 'GUID_1_3', pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, 'GUID_1_5', 'GUID_1_5', 'GUID_1_5', 'GUID_1_5'],
    'event_in': ['GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_1', 'GUID_2_2', 'GUID_2_3', 'GUID_2_4', 'GUID_2_4', 'GUID_2_4', 'GUID_2_4', pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA]
}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Drop duplicates based on values in 'event_out' and 'event_in' columns, preserving the first occurrence
df_filter = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['event_out', 'event_in'], keep='first')

# Reset the index of the filtered DataFrame
df_filter.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Display the filtered DataFrame
display(df_filter)
```

i hope it 'll help you

Comment: it will keep 3 first records for order A, but they should be for A, B, C